# Unable to translate IP addresses using tr

Tags: linux, translate, tr

I have a file that has lot of IP addresses. I need to change those IP addresses into some numbers. Below is how a file "data" will look

```
152.14.12.1
152.14.12.2
152.14.12.3
```

When I execute `cat data | tr -s '152.14.12.1' '9'`, it replaces everything and the output is `9 9 9 9`. How to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you prefer to use `sed`, to replace a string, and not `tr` that is intended for a SET of chars, like:

`cat data | sed "s/152.14.12.1/9/g"`

gives you:

```
9

152.14.12.2

152.14.12.3
```